# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE' on sql server

Tags: sql-server

I tried googling this but every post I find, the OP is using insert or join. Well I am not. I am trying to replace a string in a column, `Details` where `Name` = Service1

```
begin tran
UPDATE [User] 
SET Details WHERE Name=Service1 SELECT replace('ACC_STATUS:Deactivated', 'Deactivated',  'Activated')
rollback
```

When running this I get

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'WHERE'.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#c-using-the-where-clause

Comment: you are not setting details to anything currently. have a look at link @forrest provided. you will probably want something like details = replace() where name=service

Answer (score 2):

Assuming 'Service1' is a string, here is a rewritten version, using 'Something' as what you're trying to update Details to:

```
begin tran
UPDATE [User] 
SET Details = 'Something'
WHERE Name= 'Service1';
SELECT replace('ACC_STATUS:Deactivated', 'Deactivated',  'Activated')
rollback
```

Note that I've also added a semicolon after the update statement - when you start something new, like a separate SELECT query, that's a separate statement. I would separate those with a semicolon and put them on a new line just to be safe and make it easy for readers later.

If Service1 isn't a string - if it's a reference to some other object or a query result - then you'll need to explain more about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I think newguyin3 intended the `replace` part for the `SET` not as a separate SELECT

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name wow, you're better than me! I couldn't figure out what on earth he was aiming for there.

Comment: @BrentOzar You are SQL Guru and at the same time, your sense of humor is away from earth(fantastic), Hats Off!! I am sorry, this comment is off the topic; but, couldn't resist myself from commenting on your statement.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of a (simple) `UPDATE` is:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name = <expression_that_will_update_the_column>
WHERE <some_filters_that_decide_which_rows_to_be_updated>
  ;
```

If you want (it's not very clear, please clarify) to update `Details` and replace `'Deactivated'` with `'Activated'` when the `Details` contains the substring `'ACC_STATUS:Deactivated'`, then the following should do.

It's also not clear whether `Service1` is a column name or `'Service1'` a string to be searched in `Name` and the filter to be applied (I assumed the 2nd):

```
begin tran
    UPDATE [User] 
    SET Details = replace(Details,
                          'ACC_STATUS:Deactivated',
                          'ACC_STATUS:Activated')
    WHERE Name = 'Service1' ;
rollback ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, I think you want the "SELECT" piece in the same line as the "SET".

```
UPDATE [User] 
SET Details = replace(Details, 'Deactivated',  'Activated')
WHERE Name='Service1'
```